# How resolve app build sencha touch problem

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-cmd

I try to compil a sencha app touch 2.4 but i have this errors

> [ERR] C2001: Closure Compiler Error (Parse error. primary expression
> expected) -- compression-input:151:24 [ERR] [ERR] BUILD FAILED [ERR]
> java.lang.NullPointerException [ERR] [ERR] Total time: 35 seconds
>
> [ERR] C:\app\Sencha\Cmd\6.5.3.6\plugin.xml:333: The following error
> occurred while executing this line:
> D:....sencha\app\build-impl.xml:398:
> The following error occurred while executing this line:
> D:....sencha\app\page-impl.xml:257:
> java.lang.NullPointerException [ERR] A log is available in the file
> "D:...\sencha-error-20210623-3.log"
> [ERR] [ERR] The application was last modified by an older version of
> Sencha Cmd (6.2.1.29). [ERR] Running "sencha app upgrade" may resolve
> the error described above.

if I try upgrade .... It add a  "framework": "touch" in app.json with 2 keys

> [ERR] C:\app\Sencha\Cmd\6.5.3.6\plugins\touch\2.3\plugin.xml:303:
> com.sencha.exceptions.ExScript: Wrapped
> com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException: Failed to load JSON from
> D:....\app.json
>
> - duplicate key: framework (C:\app\Sencha\Cmd\6.5.3.6\ant\ant-util.js#849)    runSencha
>   (C:\app\Sencha\Cmd\6.5.3.6\ant\ant-util.js:848)    runAppUpgrade
>   (anonymous:270)    [anonymous] (anonymous:290)    x_app_upgrade
>   (anonymous:288) [ERR] A log is available in the file
>   "D:...\sencha-error-20210623-5.log"
>   [ERR] [ERR] The application was last modified by an older version of
>   Sencha Cmd (6.2.1.29). [ERR] Running "sencha app upgrade" may resolve
>   the error described above. [ERR]

what the problem ?

Thanks

Comment: Could you explain how you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

it's ok I hahe forgotten a directory sass ...